# Receiving API info after it responds to client (sending undefined instead of api info)

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my node.js file, what's happening is, a user inputs an id and it gets sent to the server-side, which the server then takes and searches it through an api on a third-party. The problem I am having is, the response from the initial id sent by the user gets res.end before I get the info back from the api, thus getting a big fat undefined or an empty string on the client side. How can I make it so the res.end waits until it receives the data from the api and then sends it to the client? Or am I going at it entirely wrong and shouldn't be doing it this way?

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var url = require('url');`

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var id = url.parse(req.url,false).query;

    var realId = getInfoFromApi(id);

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.writeHead(200);

    res.end(JSON.stringify(realId));

}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');

function getInfoFromApi(id) {
    var url = "https://random.com/" + id + "?api_key=blabla";

    var test = https.get(url, function(res) {
        var body = '';

        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            var theId = JSON.parse(body)
            console.log("Got response: ", theId);
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
          console.log("Got error: ", e);
    });
return test;
}
```

Any info into what I should be looking or resources that would help me would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance for any help.

Also as a bonus question, should I be using POST method instead of GET from server to api-server? Or does POST privacy only matter from client to server? I'm just curious if clever clients would be able to access the server http.requests if I use GET instead of POST or if it even matters at all since it's from the server and not the client.

Oh and another thing, I was debating if I should use https.createServer since I have to use https for https.get, that way I could remove the http module from require and only use https. Is there any big difference in performance or anything if I do that?

Thanks again in advance.

EDIT:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var id = url.parse(req.url, false).query;

    var link = "https://random.com/" + id + "?api_key=blabla";
    var testo = https.get(link, function (rez) {
        var body = '';
        rez.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        rez.on('end', function () {
            var endRes = body
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end(endRes);
        });
    }).on('error', function (e) {
        console.log("Got error: ", e);
    });
}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

I managed to change it like this after I read into callbacks. Thank you for that. It works fine now, so happy, thanks again. My question now though is, does this work flawlessly if dozens or hundreds of people are searching at the same time? Does each client connected to the server get their own seperate function *thing* that runs at their own pace without interfering with others? Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: You have to nest or chain your async operations so the response is not sent until all your async operations are done.  `getInfoFromApi(id, callback)` can take a callback and call that callback only when it is done and then you send your response only when that callback has been called.

Comment: @jfriend00 I managed to get it to work after looking into callbacks, edited with another question if you don't mind taking a look, thanks again.

Comment: Yes, each request gets its own function context so multiple requests can be in flight at the same time as long as you only use local variables and not shared variables.